# Spring Security unable to authenticate properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have Security class as following:

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

and I have also Login Rest API as following:

```
import com.company.blog.data.dto.request.LoginRequestDto;
import com.company.blog.enums.ErrorCase;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthController {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<String> signIn(@RequestBody LoginRequestDto loginRequestDto) {
        Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequestDto.getUsernameOrEmail(), loginRequestDto.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(ErrorCase.SUCCESS_LOGIN.getMessage(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

as you see , I didn't any antMatchers path configuration for Login Rest API. In that case it has to give me the following error in the POSTMAN.

```
{
  "timestamp":"",
  "status":401,
  "error":Unautorized",
  "message":"Unautorized",
  "path":"/api/auth/signin"
}
```

but login operation successfully processed. I also tried to runing debug mode, everything work fine. I couldn't understand what happened.

I am also sharing some of my security related classes below.

```
import com.company.blog.data.entity.Role;
import com.company.blog.data.entity.User;
import com.company.blog.data.repository.UserRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static com.company.blog.enums.ErrorCase.USER_NOT_FOUND;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String usernameOrEmail) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsernameOrEmail(usernameOrEmail, usernameOrEmail).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(USER_NOT_FOUND.getMessage()));
        return new UserDetail(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), mapToGrantedAuthority(user.getRoles()));
    }

    private Set<GrantedAuthority> mapToGrantedAuthority(Set<Role> roles) {
        return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

}

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import java.util.Collection;

public class UserDetail extends User {
    public UserDetail(String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
    }
}
```

Comment: You enabled basic authentication, so if the username/password is available as request headers it will just authenticatie.

Comment: I'm already doing the authentication through basic authentication, so I enabled it.

Comment: My question is: Since I haven't defined the endpoint address of the AuthController in my antMatcher() method, it has to give me the error I showed above, but it validates successfully.

Comment: @M.Deinum I created another web-service in my AuthController class is called signup and this give me error what I want .

Comment: No it shouldn't You configured everything to be authenticated, as you use basic authentication you are authenticated. This `.anyRequest().authenticated()` is basically `antMatcher("/**').authenticated()` a catch-all.